# Spark worker retry to connect to master but receive java.util.concurent.RejectedExecutionException

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have setup a cluster on 12 machine and the spark workers on slave machines could disassociate with the master everyday. That means they could looks **work well for a period of time** during a day, but then the slaves would **all** disassociate and then be shutdowned.
**The log of the worker would look like below:**

`16/03/07 12:45:34.828 INFO Worker: Retrying connection to master (attempt # 1)
16/03/07 12:45:34.830 INFO Worker: Connecting to master host1:7077...
16/03/07 12:45:34.826 INFO Worker: Retrying connection to master (attempt # 2)
16/03/07 12:45:45.830 ERROR SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[sparkWorker-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2,5,main]
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@1c5651e9 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@671ba687[Running, pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 2]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2048)
...
16/03/07 12:45:45.853 Info ExecutorRunner: Killing process!
16/03/07 12:45:45.855 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called`

**The log of the master would look like below:**
16/03/07 12:45:45.878 INFO Master: 10.126.217.11:51502 got disassociated, removing it.
16/03/07 12:45:45.878 INFO Master: Removing worker worker-20160303035822-10.126.217.11-51502 on 10.126.217.11:51502

**Information for the machines:**
40 cores and 256GB memory per machine
spark version: 1.5.1
java version: 1.8.0_45
The spark application runs on this cluster with configuration below:

`spark.cores.max=360
spark.executor.memory=32g`

Is it a memory issue on slave or on master machine?
Or is it a network issue between slaves and master machine?
Or any other problems?

Please advise.
thanks